# "The requested URL was not found on this server" afterinstalling xampp and changing port in etc folder file

Tags: php, mysql, apache, phpmyadmin, xampp

I am trying to access phpmyadmin but unfortunately I am getting an error. I have no idea how can I install phpmyadmin.

[image]

```
Not Found
The requested URL was not found on this server.

Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 80
```

Comment: have a look at this https://askubuntu.com/questions/387062/how-to-solve-the-phpmyadmin-not-found-issue-after-upgrading-php-and-apache
This will solve your error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way I could access phpmyadmin was to install [XAMPP](https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html). It installs phpmyadmin and an Apache server on your local machine. After installation, start Apache and MySQL from the xampp control panel and leave it running in the background to be able to access phpmyadmin.